# Comparing values to give different outputs

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Access database that has been converted to MySQL. I have a table, Contacts, with fields 'EmailAddress', 'HideEmailAddress', 'FaxNumber', 'HideFaxNumber', 'PhoneNumber', and 'HidePhoneNumber'.  The hide fields are all checkboxes, so have values of 1 or 0, with 1 being TRUE.

I need, either in my MySQL Select statement or in my PHP query, to be able to not show the information if the hide field has a value of 1. Also, it's pretty common that only one of the three fields will be marked as hide, so I can't do a blanket "if any of these are 1 hide all of them.' I need to output the query to a webpage, and either show or hide the three fields above depending on the value of the hide field for each column. My SELECT statement is retrieving all six values, and the PHP is turning it into an array, but I don't think anything with array comparison will help here.

I just have no idea what I should be doing here. I've been searching for a couple of days now and nothing seems to come close to what I need. I have a VERY ad-hoc if-elseif-else running in my PHP loop in order to get it done by the deadline, but that requires 9 or 12 different statements, and I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Here's my code. I've chopped it up a lot from the original query, but that query does work, so if there are typos here, it's from the chop-up. I just can't figure out how to suppress a field based on the value of another field. This is also why I have the two AS statements in the SELECT statement - in the original query, there's information coming from five different tables and there's "FaxNumber" and "EmailAddress" in both of them. I left the AS in just in case it changes things.

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = 'SELECT Contact.CompanyID, Contact.WebContact, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.WorkPhone, Contact.HidePhoneNumber, Contact.FaxNumber AS ConFaxNumber, Contact.HideFaxNumber, Contact.EmailAddress AS ConEmailAddress, Contact.HideEmailAddress FROM Contact WHERE TDAT_Contact.WebContact = "1"';

mysqli_query($dbc, $query);    

if($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) { 
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        if(($row['HidePhoneNumber'] == 1) && ($row['HideFaxNumber'] == 1)) {
    echo '<hr><div align="query"><span class="strong">Contact:</span> ' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '<br /><br /><span class="strong">Direct Email Address: </span>' . $row['ConEmailAddress'] . '</div>';    
        } elseif($row['HidePhoneNumber'] == 0) && ($row['HideFaxNumber'] == 0) {
    echo '<hr><div align="query"><span class="strong">Contact:</span> ' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Telephone: </span>' . $row['WorkPhone'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Fax: </span>' . $row['ConFaxNumber'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Email Address: </span>' . $row['ConEmailAddress'] . '</div>';}
}
     ...                          
     else { // Query didn't run.
          echo '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the data because:<br />' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
               }
            }}

   mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the connection.

?>
```

Comment: There's a parse error there (line 11). Your cut-up broke your code. We can't help you with your problem if it's not what's provided here.

Comment: Looks like I dropped a parenthesis in that line. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = 'SELECT Contact.CompanyID, Contact.WebContact, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.WorkPhone, Contact.HidePhoneNumber, Contact.FaxNumber AS ConFaxNumber, Contact.HideFaxNumber, Contact.EmailAddress AS ConEmailAddress, Contact.HideEmailAddress FROM Contact WHERE TDAT_Contact.WebContact = "1"';

mysqli_query($dbc, $query);    

if($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        echo '<hr><div align="query"><span class="strong">Contact:</span> ' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '<br />';
        if ($row['HidePhoneNumber'] == 0) {
            echo '<span class="strong">Direct Telephone: </span>' . $row['WorkPhone'] . '<br />';
        }
        if ($row['HideEmailAddress'] == 0) {
            echo '<span class="strong">Direct Email Address: </span>' . $row['ConEmailAddress'] . '<br />';
        }
        if ($row['HideFaxNumber'] == 0) {
            echo '<span class="strong">Direct Fax: </span>' . $row['ConFaxNumber'];
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else { // Query didn't run.
    echo '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the data because:<br />' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
}

mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the connection.
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it beautifully - even after I realised I had to display the data differently to accomodate the layout. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in mysql and avoid extra php coding

something like this assuming the Hide fields are booleans

```
$query = 'SELECT Contact.CompanyID, Contact.WebContact, Contact.FirstName,Contact.LastName, 
case when Contact.HidePhoneNumber then '' else Contact.WorkPhone end as WorkPhone,
case when Contact.HideFaxNumber then '' else Contact.FaxNumber end  AS ConFaxNumber,
case when Contact.HideEmailAddress then '' else Contact.EmailAddress and AS ConEmailAddress FROM Contact WHERE TDAT_Contact.WebContact = "1"';
```

then on php you just

```
if($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        echo '<hr><div align="query"><span class="strong">Contact:</span> ' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Telephone: </span>' . $row['WorkPhone'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Fax: </span>' . $row['ConFaxNumber'] . '<br /><span class="strong">Direct Email Address: </span>' . $row['ConEmailAddress'] . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a bit beyond my understanding (it looks like my post lost the line explaining that I'm pretty new to PHP) but I am going to play with it later and see if I can make this work and understand cases.

Answer (score 0):

Break your html output in small pieces, observe the common patterns, and factorize it in functions:

```
function hide($field, $label, $row){
    if ($row['Hide'.$field] == 0)
        echo '<span class="strong">'.$label.'</span>'.$row[$field].'<br/>';
}

$hiddenfields = array ('EmailAddress' => 'Email Address', 'PhoneNumber' => 'Direct Telephone' /* etc. */);

foreach($hiddenfields as $field => $label)
     hide($field,$label,$row);
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AND operator(($row['HidePhoneNumber'] == 1) && ($row['HideFaxNumber'] == 1) which means both conditions must be true to execute the conditional code.To resolve your problem  you can use 'nested loop' within your while loop and check expressions for example:

```
   $conditions=array("0"=>"phonenumber","1"=>"fax","2"=>"email") //associative array
   for($i=0;$i<count($conditions);$i++){
   if($row[$conditions[$i]]==1){
   echo $row.[$conditions[$i]];
    }
   else{
   echo "user doesn't want to share this information";
   }
  }
```

if condition returns 1  it will echo associated array member.

Comment: You may change expression accordingly//if($row[$conditions[$i]]==1)"1 or 0

Comment: Yes - the only way I could think of to meet all the conditions was to compare and see if any/all of the three values needed to be hidden. But that elseif statement I started with ... well, it WORKED, but it wasn't GOOD. :)  Thank you for this reply - I'm going to check your answer out and see if it helps me with another loop I'm having trouble with, too.